# Avoid post update event if domain was not updated or was not dirty

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-2.3, gorm-mongodb

We had registered post update event listener for all the domain classes. But its being called every time we save an existing record even if any fields of that domain class was not updated.

For example:

```
User userInstance = User.get(1)
userInstance.save()
```

That post update event listener get called for the above code where `userInstance` was not dirty. How can we avoid this?

Using grails 2.3.5 with mongo 3.0.1 with no hibernate installed.

Comment: `if( userInstance.isDirty() ) { userInstance.save() }` suffices?

Comment: Yes, we can use this, but I'm using **postUpdate** event which will always return false for **isDirty()** method call since session was already flushed & persisted.

Comment: I think you are mixing things here. Lets make clear what are you doing in postUpdate event. Above code in the question will trigger the postUpdate event. The option I provided will help not calling save() if domain object in not dirty which in turn will not trigger any kind of event. Makes sense?

Comment: Thank You for your reply @dmahapatro. Actually I'm registering a generic post update event listener where I'm tracking the recently updated domain records. But I don't want it to be fired when domain instance has not been updated. The solution you gave will work perfect but I have to use it everywhere in my code to avoid the save method call. My question is that, can't it be by implementation in gorm or should have a way to implement.